# ADB/PM command to disable data and wifi access for Apps

Tags: adb, security, privacy, firewall

Is there a way via adb shell to disable an apps access to WiFi and Data? I'd like to turn off internet for all apps and then selectively turn it on for required apps.

I know the manual way by going to `App Info`, that is not what I'm looking for. Nor for a firewall style third party app.  I'm specifically looking for a way I can script this.